# Multithreaded fft convolution in arrayfire

Tags: c++, multithreading, arrayfire

I am trying to parallelize fft convolution in arrayfire over multiple CPU threads:

```
#include <arrayfire.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <omp.h> 

using namespace af;

void printarray(const std::vector<float>& f, size_t N=10)
{
    const size_t bound=std::min(N,f.size());
    for (size_t i=0; i< bound; ++i){
        using namespace std;
        cout<<f[i];
        if (i+1<bound) cout<<", ";
        else cout<<endl;
    }
}
using namespace std;
int main() {
    std::vector<float> vec{2.0,1.0};
    cout<<"vec: "<<endl;
    printarray(vec);
    std::vector<float> kernel(10000000,5.0);
    cout<<"kernel: "<<endl;
    printarray(kernel);
    try {
#pragma omp parallel
        {
#pragma omp master
            {
                cout<<"Threads: "<<omp_get_num_threads()<<endl;
            }
            af::array af_in(vec.size(), vec.data());
            af::array af_kernel(kernel.size(), kernel.data());
            af::array tmp = af::fftConvolve(af_in, af_kernel, AF_CONV_EXPAND);
            std::vector<float> out;
            float *h = tmp.host<float>();
            size_t entries = tmp.bytes() / sizeof(float);
            for (size_t i = 0; i < entries; ++i) {
                out.push_back(h[i]);
            }
            af::freeHost(h);
            int thr_num=omp_get_thread_num();
            cout<<"Thread "<<thr_num<<" finished"<<endl; 
        }
    } catch (af::exception& e) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", e.what());
        throw;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This minimal example program `example.cpp` can be compiled using `g++ example.cpp -lafcpu -fopenmp`. But somehow it only runs the convolutions sequentially, not parallel. This can be checked for example by observing the CPU load while the program runs or by measuring runtime:

```
$ time OMP_NUM_THREADS=1 ./a.out
vec: 
2, 1
kernel: 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
Threads: 1
Thread 0 finished

real    0m1,745s
user    0m1,654s
sys 0m0,069s
$ time OMP_NUM_THREADS=8 ./a.out
vec: 
2, 1
kernel: 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5
Threads: 8
Thread 2 finished
Thread 5 finished
Thread 6 finished
Thread 1 finished
Thread 0 finished
Thread 3 finished
Thread 7 finished
Thread 4 finished

real    0m11,944s
user    0m14,552s
sys 0m0,544s
```

I guess there must be some locking mechanism inside the function `af::fftConvolve` which prevents parallel execution despite I even constructed separate `af::array` variables in the individual threads.

How can I parallelize these `af::fftConvolve` convolutions on CPU?

Comment: And when the threads are reporting when they finish, you are seeing threads 1-8? So, it looks like 8 threads are executing but your CPU usage is roughly only 100% of 1 CPU core?

Comment: @MatthewM.Yes, I added the output for different number of threads.

Comment: From the timing one can see that some parts run parallel (af::array construction?). I think there is an unnecessary critical section in `af::fftConvolve` but I did not find it in the source code. Maybe I should ask at GitHub arrayfire/arrayfire if no one can help here.

Comment: I'm compiling arrayfire. I can tell you how this code behaves on my PC.

Comment: For me this was available as a package`libarrayfire-cpu-dev` in ubuntu.

Comment: I prefer to compile from source so I don't have to install (who knows how many) packages that I won't use again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244192/discussion-between-matthew-m-and-phinz).